# DatePipe transform shows wrong date format

Tags: angular, datepicker, date-pipe

I am using Angular version 12 and datePipe.transform, I am getting date in dd/MM/yyyy format in string and I want to bind that date in my reactive form ( to edit the form ) where I use Angular material date picker [Basic Angular Date picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srh92c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I am sure I am doing something wrong but I don't know what? Can anyone help me?

**SOLUTION For me:**

[MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) is the best solution for all date and time glitches!

If you are looking for alternative of moment then below is the link you must look into it. - Thanks to [Jakub Kozak](https://medium.com/@jakub-kozak)

https://medium.com/swlh/best-moment-js-alternatives-5dfa6861a1eb

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srh92c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this:

```
    const CreatedDate1 = this.datePipe.transform(CreatedDate, 'long');
```

P.S: You were using the string '09/11/2021' instead your formatted variable 'CreatedDate'.

By the way, as a piece of advice, it's a good practice to use "CamelCase" for naming your variables and consts in Angular ('createdDate', in your example), and leave the "PascalCase" (as 'CreatedDate') for the Interface/Classes/...
I left an article about it [HERE](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/best-practice-naming-conventions-in-angular-af26430d2464)
See you!

Comment: Strange! if I use 'long' I could see November but unfortunately I cant bind long format in date picker - it needs certain date format which I have mentioned in DEMO  'yyyy-dd-MM'.. If I use that format it will show September in date picker! when "long" format shows correct result in console! @Juan Vicente Berzosa Tejero any idea?

Comment: Any other way to bind date in Angular material date picker?

Comment: your answer is right. but it could not help me in bind the  value! anyways, Thanks for the link and your time!